# Forecast period starting earlier than defined

Tags: syntax, prediction, spss, forecasting

My dataset has multiple variables and I am using TSModel for forecasting. I have data till December 2017 but a lot of them are either 0 or missing. During the forecast, it is starting the forecast from July 2015 onwards whereas it should actually start from January 2018.

Can someone help with what might have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If for a particular series all values after a given date are missing, then the estimation period for that series ends at the last observed value's date, and the beginning of the forecast period is the next date.